# How can I make Firefox restore a recently closed tab in a new tab?

Tags: firefox

I recently installed Ubuntu on a computer. Firefox (as installed by default on this system) reopens recently closed tab content in the tab that's open when I select that recently closed tab. In other installations Firefox has opened it in the background in a new tab for me.

Is there a parameter in about:config or settings I can use to have Firefox open a recently closed tab in a background tab?

Comment: Try in `about:config` to toggle the value of `browser.tabs.loadBookmarksInBackground`.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the suggestion - but it didn't work.